# How to get a list of all on_command_error error events

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make specialized errors for each error type, but I only could find the 2 I have used below. Does anyone know all the error event types from commands

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Slow Down!! :timer:", description='This command can be used again in %.2f seconds' % error.retry_after, color=0xE74C3C)
        message = await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await message.delete()
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Uh oh!", description=f"Uh oh, {ctx.author.mention} what are you trying to do?? {error}!", color=0xE74C3C)
        message = await ctx.message.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
```

The commandNotFound and CommandOnCooldown is the only types I could find and work, anyone know a list of all of them? I currently use the on_command_error but it won't be specific to address to the user what the problem is. Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little research, you can simply find all the errors from API References. [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exceptions) is the all command error exceptions.